# downloading a movie file and placing it in the Videos directory... is that possible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, nsurlrequest

I want to programattically pull a movie file down into a NSData object and write it to iPhone disk in the movies directory so that the user can open up their iPhone iPod section and watch the movies from there... Is that possible?

Or do I need within my app to create a 'viewing' area, download the files to NSHomeDirectory add a folder in Documents and store the data there?

Thanks for any answers...

Comment: have you done this successfully?And will it work for all video sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an iPhone Store application, this is not do-able, as the Movie directory is not accessible to the sandboxed application.

Of course, you're free to download the movie to a location accessible to your application, and playing the movie inside your application.

Comment: yep thats what im gonna do. bummer